# SQL query to concatenate values from joined table into primary table, based on alias value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Apologies upfront if I fail to use the correct SQL terminology/approach in this issue. What I'm looking to do is write a SQL query (using SQL Server 2008R2) for an e-commerce system which will collate order data from one table and customer data from a second table.  My SQL skills go so far as `JOIN`s, and I'm fairly certain this will involve something more comprehensive like sub-queries as the customer data storage isn't (what I'd call) straight forward. I'm not sure what approach to take.

*Note, this is a third party system so I have no control over the database schema.*

I have 2 tables:

**Orders**:

```
OrderId | OrderValue
--------------------
1       | 123
2       | 338
3       | 500
```

**CustomerData**:

```
OrderId | Alias     | Value
-------------------------------
1       | firstName | John
1       | lastName  | Smith
1       | city      | Boston
1       | zip       | 12345
1       | address1  | Someplace
2       | firstName | Jane
2       | lastName  | Doe
2       | city      | New Orleans
2       | zip       | 23456
2       | address1  | 1 Brookland Avenue
3       | firstName | Eric
3       | lastName  | Black
3       | city      | Chicago
3       | zip       | 34567
3       | address1  | Apartment 356
```

What I need to do is generate a query to output the following:

```
OrderId | OrderValue | FirstName | LastName | Address
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       | 123        | John      | Smith    | Someplace, Boston, 12345
2       | 338        | Jane      | Doe      | 1 Brookland Avenue, New Orleans, 23456
3       | 500        | Eric      | Black    | Apartment 356, Chicago, 34567
```

The 'Address' field needs to be made up of the values from the CustomerData table where the Alias values are 'address1', 'city' and 'zip', concatenated as a comma-separated string.  These fields will always be present in the CustomerData table but won't necessarily be in the same order, and won't be in the order in which they're needed in the output data-set - so I'll need to explicitly concatenate them as 'address1, city, zip'.

I'm struggling with the fact that the CustomerData values need to be selected based on the alias field, they're not table columns, which would have made life much simpler.

Could anyone advise how to go about this? The fact I've not created a starting query isn't due to laziness or lack of willing, I'm just really unsure how to get those CustomerData values through correctly, even as a sub-query.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you summarize `customers`:

```
select orderid,
       max(case when alias = 'firstName' then value end) as firstname,
       max(case when alias = 'lastName' then value end) as lastname,
       (max(case when alias = 'address1' then value end) + ',' +
        max(case when alias = 'city' then value end) + ',' +
        max(case when alias = 'zip' then value end)
       ) as address 
from customers c
group by orderid;
```

The rest of the query is just a `join` to `orders`.  You specify in the question that you know how to do that.

Actually, the `orders` could be a little tricky:

```
select c.orderid, o.ordervalue,
       max(case when c.alias = 'firstName' then c.value end) as firstname,
       max(case when c.alias = 'lastName' then c.value end) as lastname,
       (max(case when c.alias = 'address1' then c.value end) + ',' +
        max(case when c.alias = 'city' then c.value end) + ',' +
        max(case when c.alias = 'zip' then c.value end)
       ) as address 
from customers c join
     orders o
     on o.orderid = c.orderid
group by o.orderid, o.ordervalue;
```

> **EDIT:** One comma added to the end of the first line in the second query

Comment: Thanks so much. However, I'm getting an error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'.`. Is `case when` valid in SQL Server 2008R2?

Comment: There is a missing comma at the end of the first line.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you just need to pivot the customer data then join to that from orders

```
select      o.OrderId,
            o.OrderValue,
            cd.[firstName],
            cd.[lastName],
            coalesce([address1] + ', ','') + 
              coalesce([city] + ', ','') + 
              coalesce([zip],'') as Address
from        orders o
left join   (   select      *
                from        CustomerData
                pivot       (
                                max(Value)
                                for Alias in ([firstName],[lastName],[address1],[city],[zip])
                            ) p

            ) cd on o.OrderId = cd.OrderId
```

Comment: Thanks Jamie. However, it seems `CONCAT` isn't a valid function in SQL 2008R2 :(

Answer (score 0):

This is `join` based.  It may be a more efficient.

```
declare @O table(id int primary key, val int);
insert into @O values
    (1, 123)
  , (2, 338)
  , (3, 500);
declare @C table(oid int, alias varchar(20), val varchar(20));
insert into @C values
       (1, 'firstName', 'John')
     , (1, 'lastName', 'Smith')
     , (1, 'city', 'Boston')
     , (1, 'zip', '12345')
     , (1, 'address1', 'Someplace')
     , (2, 'firstName', 'Jane')
     , (2, 'lastName', 'Doe')
     , (2, 'city', 'New Orleans')
     , (2, 'zip', '23456')
     , (2, 'address1', '1 Brookland Avenue')
     , (3, 'firstName', 'Eric')
     , (3, 'lastName', 'Black')
     , (3, 'city', 'Chicago')
     , (3, 'zip', '34567')
     , (3, 'address1', 'Apartment 356');
select o.id as orderId, o.val as orderValue
     , cF.val as firstName, cl.val as lastName
   --, cC.val as city, cZ.val as zip, cA.val as address1
     , cC.val + ', ' + cZ.val + ', ' + cA.val as address
  from @O o
  join @C cF 
    on cF.oid = o.id 
   and cF.alias = 'firstName'
  join @C cL 
    on cL.oid = o.id 
   and cL.alias = 'lastName'
  join @C cC
    on cC.oid = o.id 
   and cC.alias = 'city'
  join @C cZ 
    on cZ.oid = o.id 
   and cZ.alias = 'zip'
  join @C cA
    on cA.oid = o.id 
   and cA.alias = 'address1' 
 order by o.id;

orderId     orderValue  firstName            lastName             address
----------- ----------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
1           123         John                 Smith                Boston, 12345, Someplace
2           338         Jane                 Doe                  New Orleans, 23456, 1 Brookland Avenue
3           500         Eric                 Black                Chicago, 34567, Apartment 356
```